# Nuance mobile sdk: "There appears to be a lot of background noise"

Tags: iphone

After starting the listener a couple of times I only get "There appears to be a lot of background noise" errors, in a totally quiet environment that is.

Comment: Have you tried writing them?  Unfortunately, I don't think many people here will be able to comment on their proprietary SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the listening method was called twice and the demo code didn't handle this nicely. it worked after adding this to the official code:

if (transactionState == TS_RECORDING) {
    return;
}

Comment: Hi, Can you suggest, where i need to add this statement in code?